# How do I prove the following relationship between big-theta notation and logarithms?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics

Prove that:

$\lg (\Theta(n))=\Theta(\lg n)$

Comment: What attempts have you made to solve the problem? This should be quite easy to show by simply using the definition of $\Theta$ and some basic algebra. Hint: for $f \in \Theta(n)$ and sufficiently large $n$, $c_1 n \le f(n) \le c_2 n$ for some constants $c_1,c_2 > 0$.

Comment: You should be careful with the equality sign: $\lg(\Theta(n)) \subseteq \Theta(\lg{n})$, but the converse inclusion is not true, for instance $2 \lg n$ is in $ \Theta(\lg{n})$ but not in $\lg(\Theta(n))$.

Comment: $\lg(\Theta(n))$ is not a known notation. Please give a definition.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct approach to questions of this sort that try to give a better understanding of definitions is first to look at the,

$\displaystyle f\in\Theta(\lg n)\Rightarrow c_1\lg(n)\leq f\leq c_2\lg(n)$

We want to show that $\lg(\Theta(n))$ satisfies this requirement. I think the best way would be to show that :

$\lg(\Theta(n))\leq c_1\cdot\lg(n^2)$

$\lg(\Theta(n))\geq c_2\cdot\lg(\sqrt n )$

Hope this is helpful.